# Excel macro to save jpg as attachment

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, macros, save

I'm lost with this topic. I gonna try to explain what I'm trying to do:
- the idea I have, is to be able to upload or save jpg files to my access 2010 database, this proccess is launched by usign macro in excel. I've read a lot in Internet but honestly I'm stuck, I'm not able to find an example.
I want to use ADO connection
My idea is to use post labels and this labels will be different, I mean, I want to print these labels with these pictures.

Below you can see What I'm trying to do. I'm lost, I get errors, perhaps if someone has an example I could adapt it because, I think, I am not able to use the one I have.

the procedure is as follow:

```
Sub SUBIRIMAGEN() 'To save a file in a table as binary


    Dim adoStream               As Object
    Dim adoCmd                  As Object
    Dim strFilePath             As String
    Dim adoCon                  As Object

    Const strServerName         As String = ""  'Server Name

    Set adoCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    Set adoCmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")


    strDBName = "database1.accdb"
    strMyPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    strDB = strMyPath & "\" & strDBName

'Connect to a data source:
'For pre - MS Access 2007, .mdb files (viz. MS Access 97 up to MS Access 2003), use the Jet provider: "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0". For Access 2007 (.accdb database) use the ACE Provider: "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0". The ACE Provider can be used for both the Access .mdb & .accdb files.




    '--Open Connection to SQL server
    adoCon.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    adoCon.Open ConnectionString:="Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & strDB
    Rem adoCon.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & strServerName & ";Initial Catalog = " & strDB & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    '----

    strFilePath = "C:\Users\pc2\Downloads\frutossecosgranel.JPG" ' File to upload

    adoStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    adoStream.Open
    adoStream.LoadFromFile strFilePath 'It fails if file is open

    With adoCmd
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO table1 (id,attach) VALUES (?,?) " ' Query
        .CommandType = adCmdText

        '---adding parameters
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Id", adInteger, adParamInput, 0, 1)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@attach", adVarBinary, adParamInput, adoStream.Size, adoStream.Read)
        '---
    End With

    adoCmd.ActiveConnection = adoCon
        adoCmd.Execute

    adoCon.Close


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to attach image to database access from excel.

Write this code in excel

Modify the constants as you need

```
 Private Sub AttachImage()
    Const dbname = "c:\temp\Db.accdb"
    Dim sql As String
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rst As Recordset2
    Dim rstImage As Recordset2
    Dim imageField As Field2
    Dim path As String
    Dim lnga As Integer
    Dim lngkey As Long
    path = "c:\temp\table.png"

    'select the row to be attached by image
    sql = "SELECT * FROM table2  WHERE ID =  1"
    Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase(dbname)
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(sql)

    Set imageField = rst!Blob  ' Blob is the field name to store attachment
    Set rstImage = imageField.Value
     rst.Edit
    rstImage.AddNew
    On Error Resume Next
    rstImage!FileData.LoadFromFile path
    If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error: " + Err.Description, vbInformation, path
    Exit Sub
    End If
    rstImage.Update
    rst.Update

   Set rst = Nothing
   Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```